# Refreshing JSP variable without reloading a page

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, jsp

In my web-application I use Java as a Back-end. On the Web page the user can choose, delete or edit one/several servers. The information about these servers are read from the Server. Java controller sends the JSON file to JSP page with the servers' information to be shown.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/configurations.html", method = RequestMethod.GET) public ModelAndView chooseServers(ModelMap model) throws Exception {
    try {
        //reads objects from configuration and sends to the web page as JSON file.
        String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(servers);
        System.out.println(result);
        model.addAttribute("serversList", result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ModelAndView("configurations"); }
```

The data is saved into variable as followed:

```
<html ng-app="homepage">
    <head>...</head>
    <body id="body" data-serversList='${serversList}' id="configurationsPage">
...</body>
</html>
```

I read this data in JS as followed:

```
var items = new Array();
var main = function(){
var information = $("body").attr("data-serversList");
    var serversJson  = JSON.parse(information);
    for (var i = 0; i < serversJson.list.length; i++){
        items.push({id: serversJson.list[i].id, text: serversJson.list[i].name});
    }
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

This is how I update the data on server side:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'addServer.do',//the value of SpringMVC controller
    data: ({serverObjectString : serverObjectString})
});
```

After user changes the server, deletes, adds or edits any of them, the data is reload on the server side. But on the user side it remains the same unless I do refresh. But I'm using AngularJS, that's why I have dilemma - how to keep all logic on the same JSP, but reload

> data-serversList='${serversList}'

without refreshing the page? Or is there any other approach to solve this problem?

Comment: What data would you need to refresh on the page? The `data-serversList` attribute? Can your server-side code return this data to the client after a successfull `$.ajax` call?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I guess I can only return a page or html part back. That means it will be reload - partially or complete. But in code I use the serversList variable and this variable is written in body tag. That's why I'm thinking there must be the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `asynchronous JavaScript and XML` AKA [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). Can achieve with plain JavaScript or with any third-party JavaScript library like JQuery.

Comment: Should I use my AJAX request in another way? As I see a problem, the JSP is loaded once, but it's variable is used after the data is changed. So after the data is changed, it still reads "the old" JSP. But how to avoid this problem, if I don't want to refresh the page? Maybe another way to read variable from Server-side? Otherwise my AngularJS doesn't make much sense - the user will be always pushed back to the start-point.